# Passing Multiple Json data to a list or an array in Web Api controller

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, postman

I'm trying to pass an Json array to a web api and get all that values to a single array or a list in the web api.

to test this I'm using Postman app in Google. This is my input data

```
[{
"ID":"1",
"ID":"2",
"ID":"3"
}]
```

What I want is to pass these data to a post method and get all these data into a single array or a list. How can I do this?

I need to execute the following query

```
Select * from table where ID in ("I need the data list here");
```

To do that I have to get all the data sent to from the json to a single array or a list.

Comment: Hi, sadly this isn't enough to come here and ask a question. You should prove that you've already put some effort before coming here... AFAIK, a 10 seconds query on Google should be enough to see how parameter binding works on WebAPI...

Comment: I did a bit of editing in the original question. I'm not sure whether parameter binding is the solution for my requirement

Comment: The solution is always parameter binding. Sometimes you use built-in parameter binders and other times you need to implemetn your custom ones. In your case, built-in ones are enough ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{} = json object. 
[] = json array. 
you are passing a json array with one object in it

```
[
{"ID":"1"},
{"ID":"2"},
{"ID":"3"}
]
```

Comment: OMG. This was the Problem. You are the best. Thank you so much man You saved my day